# How to create Multiple Pills/Tabs Selection Boxes in Html, Css, Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

**Can anyone have idea, how to create this type of pills/tabs in Html/CSS/Twitter Bootstrap and what they called?**

[image]

Comment: here you go https://codepen.io/chizzymamma/pen/aQwQOp

Answer (score 1):

[Check Bootstrap 4 Button Tags](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#button-tags): (icon used from [Font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io))

```css
button.btn.btn-primary {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="submit" value="Submit">Disabled <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: if you are using twitter then check that link, First logged in.

Comment: https://twitter.com/i/start/interests

Comment: the pills that will selected and also deselected, for adding the interest as we can adding in twitter, facebook, instagram or at someother platform

Comment: Nakhhhh, edited to button tags may suit best your case. I don't have twitter sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's a great idea.. ok i will ry my best

Comment: ok, where? and can u please tell me about sub checkbox, like when i click on parent checkbox the sub class of the checkbox is open?

Comment: Please tell me about parent-child checkboxes. Please